# ':react-native-reanimated' Cannot invoke "String.startsWith(String)" because "versionOutput" is null

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, npm

I accidentally unlinked react-native-reanimated from my App and started getting this error. Also worth mentioning I just upgraded to mac OS Ventura 13.2.1

`npx react-native start` failing build

I tried `cd android && ./gradlew clean`  to fix this issue and it seems it is in there is something wrong with reanimated package

The full error log:

```
> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
No AAR for react-native-reanimated found. Attempting to build from source.
Android gradle plugin: 7.3.1
Gradle: 7.5.1
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.
> Cannot invoke "String.startsWith(String)" because "versionOutput" is null

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s

Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-reanimated'.
> Cannot invoke "String.startsWith(String)" because "versionOutput" is null

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
```

I have the package in my package.json:

```
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.0.2",
```

I also have it in plugins in babel.config.js

```
['react-native-reanimated/plugin', {
    "relativeSourceLocation": true
  }]
```

I could not find any similar error log online.

When I do npm install it shows:

```
up to date, audited 1411 packages in 1s
```

Edit: A friend cloned my repo and everything worked well for them. What can I reinstall to avoid this error on my machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rolled back `reacti-native-reanimated` to version 2.14.4 in package.json

Answer (score 0):

Is the react-native-reanimated plugin listed last in babel.config.js?

Comment: Yes, looks like `module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  "plugins": [

    ["module:react-native-dotenv", {
          "moduleName": "@env",
          "path": ".env",
          "blacklist": null,
          "whitelist": null,
          "safe": false,
          "allowUndefined": true
      }],
    ["react-native-reanimated/plugin", {
    "relativeSourceLocation": true
  }]

  ],

};
`

Comment: I did something like react-native unlink react-native-reanimated , would that affect anything? If so how can I fix it.

Comment: try running the following commands in your project directory to reset your project and reinstall all dependencies:

rm -rf node_modules
npm install

Comment: Still the same error unfortunately

Comment: The Error is coming from this line:
Cannot invoke "String.startsWith(String)" because "versionOutput" is null
try searching in your project for "String.startsWith(String)". check where this line is written